# Can nagios be configured to send notifications using web services?

Tags: web-services, notifications, monitoring, nagios

From reading [this article](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/3/en/notifications.html) , it looks like `Nagios Core` is configured out of the box to send out notifications using email.

The `Helpful Resources` section does mention alternate notification mechanisms. I was wondering if there is a way to configure Nagios to send out notifications using web services.

Has anyone tried this before. Could someone please point me to some useful resources/links online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nagios can be configured to call any script (see `service_notification_commands` in `contact` definitions and `command` definitions in `command.cfg`), so, just provide a script which then calls a webservice (e.g., using wget, curl or any other technology).

See https://serverfault.com/a/480587/237109.

Comment: that's one option. Is there a nagios plugin or module that will do the same ?

Comment: for instance , something that calls the service if we provide it a payload and a wsdl.

Comment: I'm not aware of anything. Btw. SO is not the place for asking for software recommentations.

Comment: what would be an appropriate forum for such a question ?

Comment: Maybe https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/, but I doubt that you get something which works out of the box (as most WS are different). Coding a small script which calls a web service isn't a big deal...